# How to insert a new line at a specified location and move to it in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 10 lines of code in VS Code and my cursor is at the end of line 10

```
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
# line 4
...
# line 10|
```

I want to be able to insert a new line below `# line 3` and move the cursor to that new line with just one shortcut. What I am currently doing is `Ctrl + G` to move to the line `:3` and then press `Ctrl + Enter` to insert a line below.

Comment: the next time you want to add a line below line 8, what determines the line number